# Guitar digital samples library

Tags: guitar, samples

Looking for tone samples digital files, free or commercial.

So far I found Nicholaus P. Brosowsky library with 37 tones from A1.wav to G3#.wav:
https://github.com/nbrosowsky/tonejs-instruments

Here is how library sounds and used:
http://landkey.net/z/bs/stackoverflow/guitar-lib/stack-index.html

But I am looking for note samples longer than 2 sec
and with richer sound possibly covering more frets.

Chords and music library is not needed, only single tones.

Thank you.

Comment: This question was closed because you formulated it like a request for recommendation for a specific product. It would be useful if you explained more what do you need the samples for. If you look for programming guitar tracks with MIDI, there are many virtual guitar plugins that cover various sounds and articulations.

Comment: Do guitar samples exist?

If they do, would you please kindly refer them?
The primary goal for these samples is to code guitar simulation for educational site like Phet.

This forum discusses samples like in this question:
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17822/time-aligned-sound-samples?rq=1
hence I assumed this forum is a right place to ask the question.
If not, can you please advise which forum on stackexchange to go?

I also programmed an example how I am using the library in link above.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a video and audio of the coded simulator:
http://landkey.net/z/bs/stackoverflow/guitar-lib/guitar-physics-simulation.mkv.mp4
If you listen to the sound, you may find it a bit poor, I need richer samples.

Comment: If you want to use guitar sounds to play MIDI sequence for your song, google "guitar virtual instruments" and you will find many options. But most probably the license for these instruments doesn't allow to use them in another virtual instrument, so you would need to contact the authors and request a dedicated license (which they may not be willing to give).